# Auto Generate Event In PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

Is there a auto generate event in PyQt4.

That means, in normally we can connect the button event with custom definition when the button is press.

I want to generate the event to call the definition by checking global Boolean variable.

If the global variable is true, the event gonna call custom definition. 
Thanks

Comment: can you eloberate your question?

Comment: Hi, I want to call the method through the event(like button click event) and that event can be trigger without using any widget.

Comment: then simply use a while loop to check the value of the global variable. if it becomes true, call the function

Comment: I am also using with others PyQt4 widget's events. If I using while loop, the program will stuck on that loop, right.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the event by calling your button's method [.animateClick](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#animateClick)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you reply, But I always know the way of generating event over button.

Comment: Then i don't understand your question. > I want to generate the event to call the definition by checking global Boolean variable. 
If the global variable is true, the event gonna call custom definition. < `if global_boolean_variable: your_button.animateClick.trigger()`

Comment: Yes, but the True/False of global variable is control by one of widget like button. The auto generate event is triggered by checking the value of that global variable

Comment: Do you need a global variable at all? Just check the state of the "widget like button" and trigger your signal if needed